# Strange memory leak in overridden method paint in QItemDelegate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a rather big project, written in Python 3.4 and PyQt5 5.5.1. After updating to PyQt5 version 5.5.1 from PyQt5 version 5.4.1 I have strange memory leaks, there are no any leaks on 5.4.1 version. I have custom QAbstractTableModel and custom QTableView in my project with delegates for data types. Here is example code, which has memory leaks in lines 98 and 117 (it can be found using tracemalloc). Memory leak occur when you select cells in table.

Why it can be so?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
import tracemalloc 

tracemalloc.start() 

import sys 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 

RW = (Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled) 

my_array = [['00','01','02'], 
            ['10','11','12'], 
            ['20','21','22']] 

class MyWindow(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, *args): 
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args) 

        tablemodel = MyTableModel(my_array, self) 
        tableview = QTableView() 
        tableview.setModel(tablemodel) 

        self.cdelegates = [] 
        for i in range(3): 
            d = RSpinDelegate(self) 
            self.cdelegates.append(d) 
            tableview.setItemDelegateForColumn(i, d) 

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self) 
        layout.addWidget(tableview) 
        self.setLayout(layout) 
        self.startTimer(5000) 

    def timerEvent(self, e): 
        snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot() 
        top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno') 

        print("[ Top 10 ]") 
        for stat in top_stats[:10]: 
            print(stat) 

class RSpinDelegate(QItemDelegate): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None, decimals=0, step=1, range_=(0, 1e9), edit=RW, suffix='', colorfill=None, stepFilter=None): 
        super(RSpinDelegate, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.decimals = decimals 
        self.step = step 
        self.range_ = range_ 
        self.edit = edit 
        self.suffix = suffix 
        self.colorfill = colorfill 
        self.stepFilter = stepFilter 

    def setDecimals(self, decimals): 
        self.decimals = decimals 

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index): 
        if self.edit == RW: 
            if self.decimals: 
                decimals = self.decimals 
                dec = int(index.model().data(index, RBaseTableModel.DECIMALS_ROLE)) 
                decimals = dec 
                d = 10 ** (-decimals) 
                editor = RDoubleSpinBox(parent) 
                if self.stepFilter != None: 
                    editor.installEventFilter(self.stepFilter) 
                editor.setSingleStep(d) 
                editor.setDecimals(decimals) 
                editor.setRange(self.range_[0], self.range_[1]) 
                editor.setSuffix(self.suffix) 
                self._editor = editor 
                return editor 
            else: 
                editor = RSpinBox(parent) 
                if self.stepFilter != None: 
                    editor.installEventFilter(self.stepFilter) 
                editor.setSingleStep(self.step) 
                editor.setRange(self.range_[0], self.range_[1]) 
                editor.setSuffix(self.suffix) 
                self._editor = editor 
                return editor 
            return None 
        return None 

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index): 
        val = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole) 
        try: 
            editor.setValue(float(val.replace(' ', '')) if self.decimals != 0 else int(val.replace(' ', '')))
        except: 
            editor.setValue(editor.minimum()) 

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index): 
        model.setData(index, editor.value(), Qt.EditRole) 

    def getBrush(self, option): 
        brush = option.palette.base() 
        if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:# memory leak is here!
            if option.state & QStyle.State_Active: 
                brush = option.palette.highlight() 
            else: 
                brush = option.palette.light() 
        return brush 

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index): 
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect) 

    def paint(self, painter, option, index): 
        opt = QStyleOptionViewItem(option) 
        if self.colorfill: 
            brush = self.colorfill(index.model().data(index, RBaseTableModel.INDEX_ROLE), option) 
            if not(option.state & QStyle.State_Selected): 
                painter.fillRect(option.rect, brush) 
            opt.palette.setBrush(QPalette.Highlight, brush) 
        else: 
            brush = self.getBrush(option) 
            painter.fillRect(option.rect, brush)# memory leak is here!
        super(RSpinDelegate, self).paint(painter, opt, index) 

# création du modèle 
class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel): 
    refreshTable = pyqtSignal() 

    def __init__(self, datain, parent = None, *args): 
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args) 
        self.arraydata = datain 
        self.timer = self.startTimer(300) 

    def timerEvent(self, e): 
        if self.timer == e.timerId(): 
            self.refreshTable.emit() 
        else: 
            super(RBaseTableView, self).timerEvent(e) 

    def refreshTableSlot(self): 
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit() 
        self.layoutChanged.emit() 

    def rowCount(self, parent): 
        return len(self.arraydata) 

    def columnCount(self, parent): 
        return len(self.arraydata[0]) 

    def data(self, index, role): 
        if not index.isValid(): 
            return None 
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole: 
            return None 
        return (self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()]) 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    w = MyWindow() 
    w.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you add a comment above the concerned lines as there are no line numbers. It will be easier to spot them.

Comment: I have added comment "# memory leak is here!" to 98 and 117 lines.

Comment: I have the same behavior on Linux 64 bits, Qt 5.6. Using gdb as debugger and watch some variable address, I see that this watched address is overridden each time I start a timer by startTimer(int, precision). Even the variable is in dynamically linked library and startTimer() is called in the main programm. (c++ ). The same program works perfectly under Windows using mingw and compiled for 32 bits (it is even used in production for many years)